# Replacement of the variables

Tags: replacement

I have lots of functions of the form $-x_4^2+x_0 x_4-x_1 x_3-x_5 x_7+x_1 x_{13}+x_2 x_{22}$ (this is $eq_4$ see below). I want to replace each pair $x_i x_j$ by $y_l=x_i x_j$. How is it possible to do it?

```
 Do[{i, j, k} = {0, 0, IntegerDigits[l, 3][[1]]}; 
 Co[i, j, k] = Subscript[x, l], {l, 0, 2, 1}]
Do[{i, j, k} = {0, IntegerDigits[l, 3][[1]], 
   IntegerDigits[l, 3][[2]]}; 
 Co[i, j, k] = Subscript[x, l], {l, 3, 8, 1}]
Do[{i, j, k} = {IntegerDigits[l, 3][[1]], IntegerDigits[l, 3][[2]], 
   IntegerDigits[l, 3][[3]]}; 
 Co[i, j, k] = Subscript[x, l], {l, 9, 26, 1}]
Do[lam = j 3^3 + k 3^2 + n 3 + s; 
 Subscript[eq, lam] = 
  Sum[Co[j, k, m]*Co[m, n, s] - Co[k, n, m]*Co[j, m, s], {m, 0, 2, 
    1}], {j, 0, 2, 1}, {k, 0, 2, 1}, {n, 0, 2, 1}, {s, 0, 2, 1}]
```

Here $eq_k$ are the expressions containing $x_ix_j$. Below I define $y[l]$

```
 l = 0;
 Do[Do[y[l] = Subscript[x, i] Subscript[x, j]; 
  l = l + 1, {j, i, 26}], {i, 0, 26}]
```

Comment: Easiest way is probably using `Eliminate`.

Comment: You can generate the replacement equations via `replacementeqs=With[{indices = {0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 13, 22}}, 
 Equal @@@ (Transpose[{y /@ Range[Length[#]], #}] &[
    Times @@@ Tuples[Table[x[i], {i, indices}], 2]])]`. Rest should be relatively straight forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define equations

```
 Do[{i, j, k} = {0, 0, IntegerDigits[l, 3][[1]]}; 
 Co[i, j, k] = Subscript[x, l], {l, 0, 2, 1}]
Do[{i, j, k} = {0, IntegerDigits[l, 3][[1]], 
   IntegerDigits[l, 3][[2]]}; 
 Co[i, j, k] = Subscript[x, l], {l, 3, 8, 1}]
Do[{i, j, k} = {IntegerDigits[l, 3][[1]], IntegerDigits[l, 3][[2]], 
   IntegerDigits[l, 3][[3]]}; 
 Co[i, j, k] = Subscript[x, l], {l, 9, 26, 1}]
Do[lam = j 3^3 + k 3^2 + n 3 + s; 
 Subscript[eq, lam] = 
  Sum[Co[j, k, m]*Co[m, n, s] - Co[k, n, m]*Co[j, m, s], {m, 0, 2, 
    1}], {j, 0, 2, 1}, {k, 0, 2, 1}, {n, 0, 2, 1}, {s, 0, 2, 1}]
```

Define rules

```
sss = {}; l = 0;
Do[Do[AppendTo[sss, Subscript[x, i] Subscript[x, j] -> y[l]]; 
   l = l + 1, {j, i, 26}], {i, 0, 26}];
```

New equations in terms of the new variables

```
Do[Subscript[eqq, k] = Subscript[eq, k] /. sss, {k, 0, 80}];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Do[{i, j, k} = {0, 0, IntegerDigits[l, 3][[1]]};
 Co[i, j, k] = Subscript[x, l], {l, 0, 2, 1}]
Do[{i, j, k} = {0, IntegerDigits[l, 3][[1]], IntegerDigits[l, 3][[2]]};
 Co[i, j, k] = Subscript[x, l], {l, 3, 8, 1}]
Do[{i, j, k} = {IntegerDigits[l, 3][[1]], IntegerDigits[l, 3][[2]], 
   IntegerDigits[l, 3][[3]]};
 Co[i, j, k] = Subscript[x, l], {l, 9, 26, 1}]
Do[lam = j 3^3 + k 3^2 + n 3 + s;
 Subscript[eq, lam] = 
  Sum[Co[j, k, m]*Co[m, n, s] - Co[k, n, m]*Co[j, m, s], {m, 0, 2, 
    1}], {j, 0, 2, 1}, {k, 0, 2, 1}, {n, 0, 2, 1}, {s, 0, 2, 1}]
p = Flatten[Table[Subscript[x, i] Subscript[x, j] -> y[i + j],
    {j, 1, 26}, {i, 1, 26}]];
 Subscript[eq, 0] /. p

(*Out[]= -y[4] - y[8] + y[10] + y[20]*)

 Subscript[eq, 80] /. p

(*Out[]= y[32] + y[42] - y[44] - y[48]*)
```

Comment: Thanks. However, your definition of y[k] (Subscript[x, i] Subscript[x, j] -> y[i + j]) doesnt coincide with mine. Is it possible to mix loop and table?

Comment: @Chipa-Chipa I just showed how to use the rule `xx->y`. You can use any rule that does not violate symmetry $x_ix_j=x_jx_i$.